# Is it possible to force a screen reader to read the inner contents of a fieldset?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, screen-readers, fieldset

When reading a page both Chromevox and Voice Over (I don't have JAWS or NVDA) seem to skip over the inner elements of a `<fieldset>`. In the example HTML below there's a button to focus on the `<main id="content" tabindex="-1">` element:

```
<html lang="en">
<head><script>
    function focusOnContent() {
        document.getElementById('content').focus()
    }
</script></head>
<body>
    <button onclick="focusOnContent()">Focus on main</button>
    <main id="content" tabindex="-1">
        <h1>User Sign-up</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Name</legend>
            <label for="firstname">First</label>
            <input type='text' id='firstname'><br>
            <label for="lastname">Last</label>
            <input type='text' id='lastname'>
        </fieldset>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicked on the `<main>` element receives focus and the screen reader says:

> User Sign-up, Name, Submit

However, I'd like this to read as

> User Sign-up, Name, **First, Last**, Submit

Removing the `<fieldset>` element fixes the problem, but obviously I'd like to keep this as it solves other accessibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using semantically correct html, then don't worry about how the screen reader reads it.  There are too many variations and different combinations will read it differently.

There are different screen readers (Chromevox, VoiceOver, JAWS, NVDA), different browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE, Edge), different OS's (Mac, PC, Mobile), and different verbosity settings within the screen reader itself.

You can't (and shouldn't) force a screen reader to read something the way **you** think it should be read.  Screen reader users are very familiar with their setup (specific browser, OS, screen reader, and settings) and know how things should sound.

Your example above looks good.

- You have a `tabindex="-1"` on the target of a focus()
- You're using the `for` attribute of the `<label>` to point to its respective `<input>` element
- You have a `<fieldset>` and a `<legend>` to group the elements together